# Помощь по задаче

Tags: c

Числовая последовательность создается правилом на фото. Найти первые n-чисел последовательности
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю как решить, только имею такое предположение:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale>

int main(void){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int n, a0, ak, k;
    k = 1;
    a0 = 1;
    printf("Введите n:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while(k <= n){
        ak = k * (a0 + (k-1)) + (1/k);
        k++;
        printf("%d", ak);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main(void)
{
    int n;
    double a = 1;
    printf("Input n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%3d  %20.6lf\n",0,1.0);
    for(int k = 1; k <= n; ++k)
    {
        a = k*a+1.0/k;
        printf("%3d  %20.6lf\n",k,a);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;   
}
```